# Need a Probability Theory book that also focusses on Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am in search for a Probability Theory book which also contains elements and proofs from Analysis. A non-Measure Theoretic approach is most desirable. I have gone through great books like Ross but I would like some book which also discusses some Analysis, which is generally not found in more problem-oriented books like Ross, Hoel Port Stone, etc.

As an example, books having problems of the form:

> If $X$ is a non-negative continuous random variable with finite fourth order moment, show that $\lim_{x\to\infty}x^4(1-F(x))=0$ where $F$ is the c.d.f. of $X$.

I would like to solve questions of this form, and the books I have consulted do not dwell much on the Analysis-related questions.

Any such book's example will be appreciated.

Comment: The modern theory of probability is pretty much founded on measure theory; it is unlikely that you can find a rigorous treatment that _doesn't_ either overtly use measure theory or develop essentially the same theory with different words.

Comment: Can you then suggest a book that introduces Measure Theory along with Probability, the Measure Theory being at a beginner's level?

Comment: BTW the other answer (which somehow got deleted) which recommended Ash's book might have been useful, though at a bit later level

Answer (score 2):

Ash's book on Probability Theory is fantastic and covers what you want, although at a bit higher level, with some measure theory:

[http://www.amazon.com/Probability-Measure-Theory-Second-Robert/dp/0120652021/ref=asap_bc?ie=UTF8](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0120652021)

Comment: I am downloading the book. However, I feel I must be expecting too much Measure Theory from it, isn't it?

Comment: It does depend on measure theory, so that might be an issue.  I had to recommend it though, because not only is it a good book on probability, I have found it to be better on measure theory than analysis books.  So maybe you can get both from reading it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a probability book that uses real analysis but not measure theory, then you want an older book back before measure theory became so central to the subject.  I recommend Feller's two volume work, *An Introduction to Probability and Its Applications*.